# Grant FullAccess using EWS API

Tags: c#, powershell, exchangewebservices

I am trying to implement few of EMS Cmdlets function using C# with out using Powershell commands. 
How can i achieve following commands functionality in C# using EWS Managed API 2.0.

**Grant FullAccess**

```
add-mailboxpermission 'userID-1' -accessrights fullaccess -user 'userID-2'
```

**Grant SendOnBehalfOf**

```
get-mailbox 'userID-1' | foreach { $_.GrantSendOnBehalfTo += (Get-Mailbox 'userID-2').Identity; $_ } | Set-Mailbox
```

**Grant SendAs**

```
get-mailbox 'userID-1' | add-ADPermission -User 'userID-2' -extendedrights 'Send As'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't EWS is a Mailbox Access API and what your trying to do is an Administrative task so you need to use the Exchange Management Shell. You can invoke the cmdlets in your managed code using something like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj943721(v=exchg.150).aspx. The only thing you can do in EWS in regards to permission is set permission at the Mailbox Folder level (eg Inbox,Calendar etc).

Cheers
Glen

Comment: This article says it can be achieved using EWS API.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn641957(v=exchg.150).aspx

Comment: That is delegate access eg a user delegating access to certain folders in their mailbox to an assistant, this is not that same thing as what is being done with Add-MailboxPermissions which is an administrator giving full access to another Mailbox (eg access all areas). If delegate access suit you need then use it, delegate access has some added features like meeting request forwarding etc. This is also not equivalent to giving SendAs rights delegate access only gives SendOnBehalf.

Comment: How about this Glen? Can this be acheived using EWS?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36462689/get-mailboxpermission-using-c-sharp

Comment: No you can't do that with EWS but your asking exactly the same question? Why don't use the cmdlets from c#  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj943721(v=exchg.150).aspx this works and is supported

Comment: I see the EMS runs on top of windows powershell. Do i need to install Exchange Management Tools in my local machine to connect to Exchange Server?

Comment: No you can use Remote Powershell to connect to the Exchange server and execute the powershell cmdlets so all you need is Powershell installed

Comment: How about reading msExchResourceMetaData  attribute of a userId. I need to determine if its of type room or not. Here is the Q i posted. I couldnt find any good article indoing so using c# .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36704536/read-msexchresourcemetadata-property-of-a-userid

Comment: I'd use msExchRecipientDisplayType eg http://gsexdev.blogspot.com.au/2007/04/webservice-to-find-room-and-equipment.html

Comment: Thanks Glen. Your blogpost is great. But instead of searching root directory for all RoomTypes , is it possible to read the properties of a single user. I have tried setting the Directory entry to particular user and set searchscope to OneLevel but it didnt retrieve any results. I want to find if a particular resource is of type Room or Not.

Comment: Nevermind. Glen. My directory entry LDAP query was wrong. I fixed it and was able to get msExchRecipientDisplayType  property. Thanks again

Comment: Now back to running remote powershell scripts locally. But my exchange server is on different domain. Do you have blog that explains connecting to using remote powershell to different domain? Thanks

Comment: Firstly if your using Managed Code your not running Powershell script locally you executing the cmdlet with a remote call. A different domain doesn't matter if you explicitly set the credentials eg start with https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff326159(v=exchg.150).aspx but the best thing is write some code yourself (easy under 30 minutes to do) and test that and you'll answer most of your questions.

Comment: I tried using kerberos authentication but not sure what goes in kerberosUri . I tried the same server that i used in LDAP:// <servername> in http://<servername>/PowerShell but didnt work and schemaUri  as http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange. I get the following error. Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the network, and that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer.

Comment: You need to connect to an Exchange server using remote powershell I would suggest you test it first from powershell before writing any code https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd297932(v=exchg.141).aspx then translate those setting into your managed code.

Comment: Tried with useraccount as follows.$UserCredential = Get-Credential
New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://exchangeServerName/PowerShell/ -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $UserCredential. Got a output with State opened. But when i try Import-PSSession $Session, i get error Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Session'. The argument is null. Supply a non-null argument and try the command again

Comment: You need to learn to troubleshoot, eg what is the error telling you ? $Session is null. Look at the code you executed you haven't used a variable called $Session so off course its going to be null . You should have used $Session =  New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri exchangeServerName/PowerShell -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $UserCredential where $Session was the variable that was the output of the cmdlet you just ran.

Comment: I was able to import the session successfully in Powershell and now i am trying the same in managed code listed in using Kerberos. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff326159(v=exchg.150).aspx . But getting the error, The term 'Get-Users' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again

Comment: There is no cmdlet called Get-Users there is a Get-User cmdlet https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996896(v=exchg.160).aspx . (the code sample in page your referencing is incorrect probably never tested). I would suggest starting with Get-Mailbox though

Comment: Finally was able to execute Get-Mailbox cmdlet remotely in managed code. Now back to square one.I have to implement View, Grant, Revoke of Full Access, SendonBehalfOf & SendAs by using EWS API as much as possible. The ones that cant be acheived by EWS API i got to do using remote powershell. How many can be acheived by EWS API?

Comment: EWS can only be used to grant permission at the folder level or to grant Delegate access (its a user API). SendOnBehalf is granted as part of the Delegate operations but is not settable directly in EWS. My suggestion is you use Powershell for all permission related operations. EWS requires what every account your using to have full access to the Target Mailbox first. Powershell just requires the delegate RBAC admin roles. So what it comes to new mailboxes it will just work. EWS is not designed or meant to be used for administrative tasks.

Comment: For testing i added a resource as 'Send On Behalf' through EAC in mailbox delegation window, which i am not able to retrieve through EWS API service.GetDelegates(primaryAccount, true) method. But if i add a delegate through API as ,service.AddDelegates(primaryMailbox, MeetingRequestsDeliveryScope.DelegatesAndSendInformationToMe, newDelegates) i could see in 'Send as behalf' section in EAC. Why is this behaviour so?

Comment: Is the above related to my permission issue?

Comment: Delegates permissions add SendOnBehalf to the user, but it doesn't work the other way if you just add SendOnBehalf that doesn't make a user a delegate it just gives them SendOnBehalf rights, because it just a right (Access Control entry) on it own and separate from delegates which is a collection of different rights and rule settings (which includes SendOnBehalf).

Comment: So you mean to say i cant retrieve SendOnbehalf users through EWS API?

Comment: Yes you should be using Powershell for that (and again for anything permission related it doesn't make sense to use EWS for that unless your writing an application that an end user is going to use to delegate access to folders and resources in their own mailbox).

Comment: The main reason for me not want to use powershell is during recent upgrade from 2007 to 2013, the scripts are breaking in 2013. Thats the reason i want to solely use EWS API.

Comment: For example, this script no longer works and gives an error 'Method invocation failed because [System.Collections.ArrayList] doesn't contain a method named 'op_Subtraction'. get-mailbox 'userID-1' | foreach { $_.GrantSendOnBehalfTo -= (Get-Mailbox 'userID-2').Identity; $_ } | Set-Mailbox

Comment: Also for the script to add Sendas "get-mailbox 'userID-1' | add-ADPermission -User 'userID-2' -extendedrights 'Send As'" i get error too, The term 'add-ADPermission' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Comment: So just rewrite your scripts, in 2007 everything was local powershell in 2010+ its remote powershell, depending if your can run the script locally on the server or if you running them via from a workstaion (you need to deal with de-serialized types). There are many many working examples for what you want to do in 2010 and beyond on the Net. My suggestion would be throw away what you doing now and rewrite it using some of these. Also you might want to consider using Get-Command that's the easiest way of seeing what cmdlets are available in a particular powershell session.

Comment: You mean to rewrite eveyrthing using remote powershell only and forget about EWS API? Do you have a blog post that explains the limitations of EWS API? Thanks!!