# Read msExchResourceMetaData property of a UserID

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, exchange-server

How to read msExchResourceMetaData property from Active Directory of an userID. I need to determine if the entered ID is not of type ROOM. I need to acheive this using C# without powershell script.

Comment: DirectorySearcher deSearch = new DirectorySearcher();deSearch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=user)(msExchResourceMetaData=ResourceType:Room))"; But it gives all data of type rooms. But i need to find out if the given input is of type room or not. All i could find is using power shell. But i need to acheive this without powershell and use C# only.

Answer (score 0):

This blogpost fixed my issue. Thanks to Glen.
http://gsexdev.blogspot.com.au/2007/04/webservice-to-find-room-and-equipment.html